# Reverse an array without using iteration

Tags: c, algorithm

A question was asked to me today and I do not believe it is possible, but I could be wrong or am over thinking it. How can you reverse an array without using iteration in C?

My thought is that it's impossible because of the fact that the array can be any size and that no C program can be expressed with that kind of support in mind without using some form of iteration.

Comment: Was this a classroom question? Interview question? General puzzle question?

Comment: An example is probably a good idea: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 } turns into { 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 } in memory.

Comment: +1. It may be impossible. But we need some proof or a group of people to confirm whether its possible or not. :)

Comment: This will mostly comes down to definitions, like exactly what does/doesn't fall within "iteration".

Comment: Iteration here refers to **for(;;)/while()**, as i think. So recursion could be the solution. If we are to refer Iteration as accessing all the elements then its impossible.

Comment: If you equate recursion with iteration then we can say with some certainty that the task is impossible, since reversing requires that each element be touched, resulting in a lower bound of O(n).  There are algorithms that are sublinear on arrays, like binary search (logaritmic time) or element access (constant time) but reverse requires examining the value of each element.

Comment: If you really wanted to get creative would it not be possible to change the OS memory manager to allow a block of memory to be reversed so that the logical beginning now points to the old physical end and then subtract instead of add for the pointer arithmetic? There would be no good reason to implement this and it would add a lot of overhead, but if you did it in Linux you would be doing it in C. :)

Comment: Hi. Your comment on Kalai's answer about his/her solution being iterative but being disguised as recursion is, of course, **correct**. Kalai's answer is an _iterative_ algorithm packaged in a recursive function. The author of your accepted answer is absolutely sure that Kalai's method is the correct recursive solution. However, if you read my answer, you'll see that the author of your accepted answer doesn't fully understand recursion. Please reconsider your acceptance after reading all answers, especially my explanation **and examples** of what true recursion is. Thanks.

Comment: ... and if you read my comment on aps2012's answer comparing mergesort to insertion sort, you'll see that aps2012 doesn't understand recursion either :-P

Comment: @aps2012 Haven't seen this question in a long time, but if you were referring to my answer note that I said "IF one takes recursion as (simply) an alternative to iteration, then Kalai's answer is correct."  I don't see that as being "absolutely sure" nor as "not understanding recursion." :-) No worries, though -- just trying to clarify.  OBTW I _do_ like your answer and upvoted it long ago.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The answer to your question is that, **yes, it is possible to reverse an array without iteration**. The phrasing of the question itself might be ambiguous, however, the spirit of the question is obvious: a recursive algorithm can be used; and there is no ambiguity at all as to the meaning of *recursive* in this sense.

If, in an interview situation with a top-flight company, you were asked this question, then the following pseudo-code would be sufficient to demonstrate you **truly understood** what is meant by recursion:

```
function reverse(array)

    if (length(array) < 2) then
        return array

    left_half = reverse(array[0 .. (n/2)-1])
    right_half = reverse(array[(n/2) .. (n-1)])

    return right_half + left_half

end
```

For example, if we have an array of 16 elements containing the first 16 letters of the Latin Alphabet, [A]..[P], the above reverse algorithm could be visualised as follows:

```
                   Original Input

1.                ABCDEFHGIJKLMNOP                   Recurse
2.        ABCDEFGH                IJKLMNOP           Recurse
3.    ABCD        EFGH        IJKL        MNOP       Recurse
4.  AB    CD    EF    GH    IJ    KL    MN    OP     Recurse

5. A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P    Terminate

6.  BA    DC    FE    HG    JI    LK    NM    PO     Reverse
7.    DCBA        HGFE        LKJI        PONM       Reverse
8.        HGFEDCBA                PONMLKJI           Reverse
9.                PONMLKJIHGFEDCBA                   Reverse

                  Reversed Output
```

Any problem that is solved with a recursive algorithm follows the **Divide and Conquer** paradigm, namely that:

1. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where each sub-problem is smaller than, but can be solved in a similar manner to, the original problem (**Divide**).
2. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where each sub-problem is independent and can be solved either recursively, or in a straightforward manner if small enough (**Conquer**).
3. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where the results of those sub-problems are combined to give the solution for the original problem (**Combine**).

The pseudo-code above for reversing an array strictly satisfies the above criteria. Thus, it can be considered a recursive algorithm and we can state without any doubt that reversing an array can be done without using iteration.

---

**ADDITIONAL BACKGROUND INFORMATION

The difference between Iteration, Recursive Implementations and Recursive Algorithms**

It is a common misunderstanding that a recursive implementation means an algorithm is recursive. They are not equivalent. Here is a definitive explanation as to why, including a detailed explanation of the above solution.

---

**What are Iteration and Recursion?**

Back in 1990, three of the most respected scholars of modern algorithm analysis in the field of computer science, [Thomas H. Cormen](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/author/default.asp?aid=344), [Charles E. Leiserson](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/author/default.asp?aid=345) and [Ronald L. Rivest](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/author/default.asp?aid=346), released their much acclaimed *[Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=3440)*. In this book, which represented the coming together of over 200 respected texts in their own right, and which for over 20 years has been used as the first and only text for teaching algorithms in most of the top-flight universities around the world, Mssrs. Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest were explicit about what constitutes *Iterating* and what constitutes *Recursing*.

In their analysis and comparison of two classic sorting algorithms, *Insertion Sort* and *Merge Sort*, they explain the fundamental properties of iterative and recursive algorithms (sometimes termed **incremental** algorithms to disambiguate when the classical mathematical notion of [iteration](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/iteration?q=iteration) is being used in the same context).

Firstly, Insertion Sort is classified as an Iterative algorithm, with its behaviour summarised as follows:

> Having sorted the subarray A[1..*j*-1], we insert the single item A[*j*] into its proper place, yielding the sorted array A[1..*j*].

*Source: [Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=3440) - Cormen, Leisersen, Rivest, 1990 MIT Press*

This statement classifies an Iterative algorithm as one that relies on the result or state of a previous execution ("iteration") of the algorithm, and that such results or state information are then used to solve the problem for the current iteration.

Merge Sort, on the other hand, is classified as a recursive algorithm. A recursive algorithm conforms to a processing paradigm called **Divide and Conquer** which is a set of three fundamental criteria that differentiate the operation of recursive algorithms from non-recursive algorithms. An algorithm can be considered recursive if, during the processing of a given problem:

1. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where each sub-problem is smaller than, but can be solved in a similar manner to, the original problem (**Divide**).
2. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where each sub-problem can be solved either recursively, or in a straightforward manner if small enough (**Conquer**).
3. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where the results of those sub-problems are combined to give the solution for the original problem (**Combine**).

*Reference: [Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=3440) - Cormen, Leisersen, Rivest, 1990 MIT Press*

Both Iterative algorithms and Recursive algorithms continue their work until a *terminating condition* has been reached. The terminating condition in Insertion Sort is that the *j*'th item has been properly placed in the array A[1..*j*]. The terminating condition in a Divide and Conquer algorithm is when Criteria 2 of the paradigm "bottoms out", that is, the size of a sub-problem reaches a sufficiently small size that it can be solved without further sub-division.

It's important to note that the Divide and Conquer paradigm requires that sub-problems must be solvable in a similar manner to the original problem to allow recursion. As the original problem is a standalone problem, with no outside dependencies, it follows that the sub-problems must also be solvable as if they were standalone problems with no outside dependencies, *particularly on other sub-problems*. This means that sub-problems in Divide and Conquer algorithms should be naturally **independent**.

Conversely, it is equally important to note that input to iterative algorithms is based on previous iterations of the algorithm, and so must be considered and processed in order. This creates dependencies between iterations which prevent the algorithm dividing the problem into sub-problems that can be recursively solved. In Insertion Sort, for example, you cannot divide the items A[1..*j*] into two sub-sets such that the sorted position in the array of A[*j*] gets decided before all items A[1..*j*-1] have been placed, as the real proper position of A[*j*] may move while any of A[1..*j*-1] are being themselves placed.

**Recursive Algorithms vs. Recursive Implementations**

The general misunderstanding of the term *recursion* stems from the fact there is a common and wrong assumption that a recursive *implementation* for some task automatically means that the problem has been solved with a recursive *algorithm*.  Recursive *algorithms* are not the same as recursive *implementations* and never have been.

A recursive implementation involves a function, or group of functions, that eventually call themselves in order to solve a sub-portion of the overall task in exactly the same manner that the overall task is being solved in. It happens that recursive *algorithms* (i.e, those that satisfy the Divide and Conquer paradigm), lend themselves well to recursive implementations. However, recursive algorithms can be implemented using just iterative constructs like `for(...)` and `while(...)` as all algorithms, including recursive algorithms, end up performing some task repeatedly in order to get a result.

Other contributors to this post have demonstrated perfectly that iterative algorithms can be implemented using a recursive function. In fact, recursive implementations are possible for *everything* that involves iterating until some terminating condition has been met. Recursive implementations where there is no Divide or Combine steps in the underlying *algorithm* are equivalent to iterative implementations with a standard terminating condition.

Taking Insertion Sort as an example, we already know (and it has been proven) that Insertion Sort is an iterative algorithm. However, this does not prevent a recursive *implementation* of Insertion Sort. In fact, a recursive implementation can be created very easily as follows:

```
function insertionSort(array)

    if (length(array) == 1)
        return array
    end

    itemToSort = array[length(array)]
    array = insertionSort(array[1 .. (length(array)-1)])

    find position of itemToSort in array
    insert itemToSort into array

    return array

end
```

As can be seen, the implementation is recursive. However, Insertion Sort is an iterative algorithm and this we know. So, how do we know that even by using the above recursive implementation that our Insertion Sort algorithm hasn't become recursive? Let us apply the three criteria of the Divide and Conquer paradigm to our algorithm and check.

1. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where each sub-problem is smaller than, but can be solved in a similar manner to, the original problem.

   **YES**: Excluding an array of length one, the method for inserting an item A[*j*] into its proper place in the array is identical to the method used to insert all previous items A[1..*j*-1] into the array.
2. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where each sub-problem is independent and can be solved either recursively, or in a straightforward manner if small enough.

   **NO**: Proper placement of item A[*j*] is wholly *dependent* on the array containing A[1..*j*-1] items and those items being sorted. Therefore, item A[*j*] (called *itemToSort*) is not put in the array before the rest of the array is processed.
3. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where the results of those sub-problems are combined to give the solution for the original problem.

   **NO**: Being an iterative algorithm, only one item A[*j*] can be properly placed in any given iteration. The space A[1..*j*] is not divided into sub-problems where A[1], A[2]...A[*j*] are all properly placed independently and then all these properly placed elements combined to give the sorted array.

Clearly, our recursive implementation has not made the Insertion Sort algorithm recursive in nature. In fact, the recursion in the implementation in this case is acting as *flow control*, allowing the iteration to continue until the terminating condition has been met. Therefore, using a recursive implementation did not change our algorithm into a recursive algorithm.

**Reversing an Array Without Using an Iterative Algorithm**

So now that we understand what makes an algorithm iterative, and what makes one recursive, how is it that we can reverse an array "without using iteration"?

There are two ways to reverse an array. Both methods require you to know the length of the array in advance. The iteration algorithm is favoured for its efficiency and its pseudo-code looks as follows:

```
function reverse(array)

    for each index i = 0 to (length(array) / 2 - 1)
        swap array[i] with array[length(array) - i]
    next

end
```

This is a purely iterative algorithm. Let us examine why we can come to this conclusion by comparing it to the Divide and Conquer paradigm which determines an algorithm's *recursiveness*.

1. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where each sub-problem is smaller than, but can be solved in a similar manner to, the original problem.

   **YES**: Reversal of the array is broken down to its finest granularity, elements, and processing for each element is identical to all other processed elements.
2. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where each sub-problem is independent and can be solved either recursively, or in a straightforward manner if small enough.

   **YES**: Reversal of element *i* in the array is possible without requiring that element *(i + 1)* (for example) has been reversed or not. Furthermore, reversal of element *i* in the array does not require the results of other element reversals in order to be able to complete.
3. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where the results of those sub-problems are combined to give the solution for the original problem.

   **NO**: Being an iterative algorithm, only one calculation stage is performed at every algorithm step. It does not divide problems into subproblems and there is no merge of the results of two or more sub-problems to get a result.

The above analsys of our first algorithm above confirmed that it does not fit the Divide and Conquer paradigm, and therefore cannot be considered to be a recursive algorithm. However, as both criteria (1) and criteria (2) were satisifed, it is apparent that a recursive algorithm could be possible.

The key lies in the fact that the sub-problems in our iterative solution are of the smallest possible granularity (i.e. elements). By dividing the problem into successively smaller and smaller sub-problems (instead of going for the finest granularity from the start), and then merging the results of the sub-problems, the algorithm can be made recursive.

For example, if we have an array of 16 elements containing the first 16 letters of the Latin Alphabet (A..P), a recursive algorithm would visually look as follows:

```
                   Original Input

1.                ABCDEFHGIJKLMNOP                   Divide
2.        ABCDEFGH                IJKLMNOP           Divide
3.    ABCD        EFGH        IJKL        MNOP       Divide
4.  AB    CD    EF    GH    IJ    KL    MN    OP     Divide

5. A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P    Terminate

6.  BA    DC    FE    HG    JI    LK    NM    PO     Conquer (Reverse) and Merge
7.    DCBA        HGFE        LKJI        PONM       Conquer (Reverse) and Merge
8.        HGFEDCBA                PONMLKJI           Conquer (Reverse) and Merge
9.                PONMLKJIHGFEDCBA                   Conquer (Reverse) and Merge

                  Reversed Output
```

From top level, the 16 elements are progressively broken into smaller sub-problem sizes of exactly equal size (levels 1 to 4) until we reach the finest granularity of sub-problem; unit-length arrays in forward order (step 5, individual elements). At this point, our 16 array elements still appear to be in order. However, they are at the same time also reversed as a single element array is also a reversed array in its own right. The results of the single-element arrays are then merged to get eight reversed arrays of length two (step 6), then merged again to get four reversed arrays of length four (step 7), and so on until our original array has been reconstructed in reverse (steps 6 to 9).

The pseudo-code for the recursive algorithm to reverse an array looks as follows:

```
function reverse(array)

    /* check terminating condition. all single elements are also reversed
     * arrays of unit length.
     */
    if (length(array) < 2) then
        return array

    /* divide problem in two equal sub-problems. we process the sub-problems
     * in reverse order so that when combined the array has been reversed.
     */
    return reverse(array[(n/2) .. (n-1)]) + reverse(array[0 .. ((n/2)-1)])

end
```

As you can see, the algorithm breaks the problem into sub-problems until it reaches the finest granularity of sub-problem that gives an instant result. It then reverses the results while they are being merged to give a reversed result array. Although we think that this algorithm is recursive, let us apply the three critera for Divide and Conquer algorithms to confirm.

1. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where each sub-problem is smaller than, but can be solved in a similar manner to, the original problem.

   **YES**: Reversing the array at level one can be done using exactly the same algorithm as at level 2, 3, 4, or five.
2. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where each sub-problem is independent and can be solved either recursively, or in a straightforward manner if small enough.

   **YES**: Every sub-problem that is not unit length is solved by splitting the problem into two independent sub-arrays and recursively reversing those sub-arrays. Unit length arrays, the smallest arrays possible, are themselves reversed so providing a terminating condition and a guaranteed first set of combine results.
3. The problem is divided into [two or more] sub-problems where the results of those sub-problems are combined to give the solution for the original problem.

   **YES**: Every problem at levels 6, 7, 8, and 9 are composed only of results from the level immediately above; i.e. of their sub-problems. Reversal of the array at each level results in a reversed result overall.

As can be seen, our recursive algorithm passed the three criteria for the Divide and Conquer paradigm and so can be considered a truly recursive algorithm. Therefore, it *is possible to reverse an array without using an iterative algorithm.*

It is interesting to note that our original iterative algorithm for array reversal can be *implemented* using a recursive function. The pseudo code for such an implementation is as follows:

```
function reverse(array)

    if length(array) < 2
        return
    end

    swap array[0] and array[n-1]
    reverse(array[1..(n-1)])

end
```

This is similar to solutions proposed by other posters. This is a recursive *implementation* as the defined function eventually calls itself to repeatedly perform the same task over all the elements in the array. However, this does **not** make the *algorithm* recursive, as there is no division of the problems into sub-problems, and there is no merging of the results of sub-problems to give the final result. In this case, the recursion is simply being used as a flow-control construct, and algorithmically the overall result can be proved to be performing the same sequence of steps, in exactly the same order, as the original iterative algorithm that was proposed for the solution.

That is the difference between an **Iterative Algorithm**, a **Recursive Algorithm**, and a **Recursive Implementation**.

Comment: Did you actually _type_ this?!

Comment: The initial solution I knew instantly; it's a textbook use of recursion. The background of it took a few days to write. Most importantly, the Original Poster has potentially been misinformed and accepted the wrong answer. That's what I wanted to fix.

Comment: @aps2012 I think you meant Latin alphabet, as there are only Roman numbers used now

Comment: I don't see how I'm misinformed if I state that a recursive implementation can be an implementation of an iterative algorithm.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray I would not call you misinformed.  The term recursive means many things.  For example there is recursive function theory.  There are recursive languages (as opposed to recursively enumerable). The CLR distinction between recursive and iterative, while very useful and well-known to professors and students in Data Structures, is rather academic and not IMHO in common usage among most developers.  You're certainly not misinformed.  It is good to have a sense of the difference, however!

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray You're not misinformed for stating it. In fact, I agreed with you because you were correct. It was Kalai's comment to you that he said that reversing an array with recursion was impossible. I wasn't sure whether you took his comment seriously or not and I just wanted to make sure you didn't go away thinking the wrong thing. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. I was a bit confused. Reading back now I see the cause for your concern. Thanks :)

Comment: -1 despite the nice recursive algorithm because your distinction between recursive "algorithms" and "implementations" is entirely imaginary. An iterative algorithm is simply a recursive algorithm in which one of the subproblems is always a base case: iterative algorithms \subset recursive algorithms. Let me clear up your confusion about insertion sort: We have IS(x:rest) = merge(IS(x), IS(rest)), with IS(x) = x.  The merging of the element x into the rest of the list is **no different from** the merging that mergesort does after splitting the problem in two!

Comment: Agree with j_random_hacker here.  I don't think we will ever get everyone on board with a single definition of "recursive algorithm."  Should this term _require_ "the results of subproblems to be **combined**" to form an answer?  "Combining" here is tricky: in a recursive implementation of binary search you are not "combining" anything, you are just throwing away half the space.  And yet we would say it is recursive precisely because it _solves subproblems in exactly the same way_.  I can see this both ways but IMHO it is kind of a quibble.  Just agreeing to disagree, Cheers. :)

Comment: @RayToal: Thanks, I appreciate your efforts to be diplomatic, and I agree that there's room for debate over exactly what recursion means (e.g. is it still "recursion" if a tail-recursive function is compiled down to an iterative loop?), but I have to insist that aps2012's taxonomy is objectively wrong (s/he forgot about combining solved subproblems) and confusing.  With the number of upvotes s/he has (I presume based on length of the post and the mentioning of Cormen et al.), it's misleading many people!

Comment: +1 for the amazing formatting work and for the graphics with ASCII ART :D

Comment: I have upclicked, but have a question:  Was the line: `ABCDEFHGIJKLMNOP` supposed to be: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP`?  (G & H swapped)

Answer (score 23):

As people have said in the comments, it depends on the definition of iteration.

### Case 1. Iteration as a programming style, different from recursion

If one takes recursion (simply) as an *alternative* to iteration, then the recursive solution presented by Kalai is the right answer.

### Case 2. Iteration as lower bound linear time

If one takes iteration as "examining each element," then the question becomes one of whether array reversal requires linear time or can be done in sublinear time.

To show there is no sublinear algorithm for array reversal, consider an array with *n* elements.  Assume an algorithm *A* exists for reversal which does not need to read each element.  Then there exists an element `a[i]` for some `i` in `0..n-1` that the algorithm never reads, yet is still able to correctly reverse the array.  (**EDIT**: We must exclude the middle element of an odd-length array -- see the comments below from this range -- see the comments below -- but this does not impact whether the algorithm is linear or sublinear in the asymptotic case.)

Since the algorithm never reads element `a[i]` we can change its value.  Say we do this. Then the algorithm, having never read this value at all, will produce the same answer for reversal as it did before we changed its value.  But this answer will not be correct for the new value of `a[i]`.  Hence a correct reversal algorithm which does not at least read every input array element (save one) does not exist.  Hence array reversal has a lower bound of O(n) and thus *requires* iteration (according to the working definition for this scenario).

(Note that this proof is only for array reversal and does not extend to algorithms that truly have sublinear implementations, like binary search and element lookup.)

### Case 3. Iteration as a looping construct

If iteration is taken as "looping until a condition is met" then this translates into machine code with conditional jumps, known to require some serious compiler optimization (taking advantage of branch prediction, etc.)  In this case, someone asking if there is a way to do something "without iteration" may have in mind *loop unrolling* (to straight line code).  In this case you can in principle write straight-line (loop-free) C code.  But this technique is not general; it only works if you know the size of the array beforehand.  (Sorry to add this more-or-less flippant case to the answer, but I did so for completeness and because I have heard the term "iteration" used in this way, and loop unrolling is an important compiler optimization.)

Comment: " But this answer will not be correct for the new value of a[i]. " wrong. this is not reverse sorting. reversal is independent of stored values. In any array of odd length you don't need to read the middle element at all.

Comment: @WillNess: The element at the middle of an odd-length array is the *only* element you can safely avoid reading.  IOW you can skip reading only O(1) of O(n) elements.  Ray's proof would be better if it addressed this corner case (and if it said "But *we can always choose a value for a[i] such that* this answer will not be correct for the new value of a[i]") but his reasoning, and the O(n) lower bound, is fundamentally sound.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I don't follow. reversal is independent of the stored values. Imagine stored values are complex structs and array cells hold pointers to these values; then reversal doesn't have to read any value even once, it only swaps pointers stored in cells. And in fact the Q relates to the array's implementation. You can implement an array such that reversing takes O(1) time, easily. Just put an addressing adapter on top of it.

Comment: @WillNess: Even if the array elements are complex structs, O(n) - 1 = O(n) pointers will need to be swapped => O(n) work. Building a reversing adaptor is often a good idea, since it will allow O(1) lookups, but that's going outside the problem definition -- likewise, you can create a rotated view of an array with an adaptor that uses an offset, but that's not the same thing as rotating its elements :)

Comment: @WillNess: To be as clear as possible: for this question, a function A[i] is specified a priori that returns the value at position i in array A; we are asked to rearrange A so that it winds up reversed *with respect to this function*. For the purposes of this question, we aren't allowed to construct a new function A'[i] such that the array is reversed w.r.t. it.

Comment: @WillNess: Sorry to flood you with responses, but I think your point about using an adaptor is still an interesting interpretation of the question. Maybe the person who asked the OP this question intended it as a "trick question" :) If you post it as an answer, making clear that it doesn't address what I'll call a "rigorous" interpretation of the question, I'll +1 it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thank you for responding. :) I don't contest that reversing by swapping is O(n), and the reason I didn't put an answer with adaptor concept here is that I too thought the question was about physically reversing an array. But, I can't understand what changing a value at some `i` has got to do with reversing. Reversing is ignorant of values, it is by-position - this was my point - so changing a value at any `i` can't prove anything about the reversing.

Comment: @WillNess: Let me try to flesh out the proof idea a bit more: basically what we need to do is munge the array A in some way so that, if we give the resulting A back to a person who had made a copy of the original A (let's call that B), they could check that it "appears" to be reversed -- i.e. that the condition A[i] == B[n-i-1] holds for all 0 <= i < n.  Now suppose there was a sublinear algorithm that achieved sublinearity by not looking at some position j (other than the middle position!)  If this algorithm correctly appeared to reverse some particular array A, it must be the case that...

Comment: A[j] == A[n-j-1] happened to be true at the outset, since if these 2 elements were different then when this person tested that particular condition it would fail and the algorithm would be observed to fail on this particular array.  Assuming only that our datatype contains more than one distinct value, it is now possible to construct some new array C that is identical to A except that at position C[j] it contains some element *other than* A[n-j-1] (any one will do).  The sublinear algorithm now must fail on this array C.

Comment: @WillNess: In short the proof is saying "For any sublinear algorithm and any input array, either the algorithm fails on that input, or if it happens to succeed, then we can trivially modify the input to produce a different input that will provably cause it to fail". Therefore there always exists at least one input on which the algorithm fails, meaning the algorithm doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks WillNess for pointing out the middle-of-odd-element edge case and j_random_hacker for phrasing the proof much better than I did.  OBTW I really like the index adaptor idea!  In the everything-is-immutable world of Clojure and ML, where immutabale data structures are shared and we tend to see only views, such an adaptor makes sense.

Answer (score 15):

**Use recursive function.**

```
void reverse(int a[],int start,int end)
{
     int temp;
     temp = a[start];
     a[start] = a[end];
     a[end] = temp;


    if(start==end ||start==end-1)
       return;
    reverse(a, start+1, end-1);
}
```

Just call the above method as **reverse(array,0,lengthofarray-1)**

Comment: Recursion is disguised iteration. In the end, CPU accesses memory iteratively anyway. Only with useless overhead.

Comment: Actually , even i thought of this method. But , if visiting every element is called ITERATION. Then this is also iterating the array.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of originally, but it's still a form of iteration (so I'm told).

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray Then it is impossible to reverse an array.

Comment: This is a recursive _implementation_, **not** a recursive **algorithm**. You've simply taken an iterative solution and used function calls to do your flow control instead of `for(...)` or `while(...)`. Have a go at writing a recursive algorithm to solve this problem. _Hint_: such an algorithm will not have an O(_n_) running time such as the implementation you've provided, but it will be properly recursive.

Comment: @aps2012, this *is* a recursive algorithm: it is essentially the same as `rev(a) = (a[n]) + rev(a[2..n-1]) + (a[1])` (with the appropriate stopping conditions).

Comment: @dbaupp It is not a recursive algorithm. It is a recursive _implementation_. Recursive Algorithms match the Divide And Conquer Paradigm. This is Stack Overflow, so if you believe that this is a recursive _algorithm_,  please post your own answer and share your wisdom with us, in detail as I have, how the your algorithm you've provided matches the Divide and Conquer paradigm.

Comment: @aps2012, arguing over definitions is pointless (and this is what this is), but, common usage suggests that this answer is recursion: except for your answer, [all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Formal_definitions_of_recursion) the [definitions](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/) of [recursion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Recursion.html), including [recursive algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursive_algorithms) I have seen are not just restricted to divide-and-conquer.

Comment: (Furthermore, your passive-aggressive statement "share your wisdom, in detail as I have" is unnecessary, please refrain from doing that in future; something like "If you could explain yourself more I would appreciate it" would be much better.)

Comment: @dbaupp This is open forum where answers must be backed up with theory and proof. If you can't take being challenged to provide rigour and proof over your views then maybe Stack Overflow isn't for you.

Comment: @aps2012, I did backup my view: this answer satisfies the conventional definition of "recursive algorithm". Did you not read the 4 links I provided? (Anyway, I hate arguing from authority but: I've been around here longer than you (and have more "reputation" and a higher average reputation per answer), so I probably understand the dynamics of SO a little better. :) )

Comment: Of course this is a recursive algorithm. aps2012 is confused: s/he is forgetting that divide & conquer algorithms often require a "combine" step (e.g. mergesort must merge together the two sorted halves). This is obviously permitted for *all* recursive/D&C algorithms, so simply including a "combine" step does not prevent your algorithm from being recursive/D&C. Iterative algorithms are simply recursive algorithms in which one of the two subproblems is always a base case and therefore requires no further processing.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a recursive function to reverse a sorted array. Ie, given the array [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] your
procedure should return [5, 4, 3, 2, 1].

Comment: No reason to add an answer to an already answered question. This doesn't add any value here and you won't get any upvotes either unless yours is different than the answers already stated. Try your hand at questions without any accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
void reverse(int a[], int start,  int end )
{
     std::cout<<a[end] <<std::endl;
    if(end == start)
       return;         
    reverse(a, start, end-1);
}
```

This looks better way as even we don't require loop to print the array values .

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3yrtpftcj [link for running test cases]

Comment: Agreed as still older recursive solution we need to print the values through iteration and my interview wasn't agreed on that approach . Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2997518/user2997518

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat solution using recursion in a javascript function. It does not require any parameters other than the array itself.

```
/* Use recursion to reverse an array */
function reverse(a){
    if(a.length==undefined || a.length<2){
        return a;
    }
    b=[];
    b.push(reverse(copyChop(a)));
    b.push(a[0]);
    return b;
    /* Return a copy of an array minus the first element */
    function copyChop(a){ 
        b=a.slice(1); 
        return b;
    }
}
```

Call it as follows;

```
reverse([1,2,3,4]);
```

Note that if you don't use the nested function copyChop to do the array slicing you end up with an array as the first element in your final result. Not quite sure why this should be so

Comment: This question is tagged as C so why are giving a Javascript solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include<stdio.h>


   void rev(int *a,int i,int n)
  {

if(i<n/2)
{
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i]=a[n-i-1];
    a[n-i-1]=temp;
    rev(a,++i,n);
 }
}
int main()
    {
    int array[] = {3,2,4,5,6,7,8};
   int len = (sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));
   rev(array,0,len);    
   for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
    printf("\n array[%d]->%d",i,array[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int v[], int v_start, int v_middle, int v_end) {
    int *aux = calloc(v_middle - v_start, sizeof(int));
    
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = v_start; i <= v_middle; i++) {
        aux[k] = v[i];
        k = k + 1;
    }

    k = v_start;
    for(int i = v_middle + 1; i <= v_end; i++) {
        v[k] = v[i];
        k = k + 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= v_middle - v_start; i++) {
        v[k] = aux[i];
        k = k + 1;
    }
}

void divide(int v[], int v_start, int v_end) {
    if(v_start < v_end) {
        int v_middle = (v_start + v_start)/2;
        divide(v, v_start, v_middle);
        divide(v, v_middle + 1, v_end);
        swap(v, v_start, v_middle, v_end);
    }
}

int main() {
    int v[10] = {4, 20, 12, 100, 50, 9}, n = 6;
    
    printf("Array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    divide(v, 0, n - 1);

    printf("Reversed: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```