# How to reverse an array without a loop or creating new array

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

```
class ReverseArrayElements1
{
  public static void main ( String[] args )
  {
    int[] values = {10, 20, 30, 40}; 
    int temp;

     System.out.println( "Original Array: " + values[0] + "\n" + values[1] +
                         "\n" + values[2] + "\n" + values[3]   );

    // reverse the order of the numbers in the array



    System.out.println( "Reversed Array: " + values[0] + "\n" + values[1] + "\n"
                         + values[2] + "\n" + values[3] );
   }
}
```

Task
I need to complete the program so that the numbers in the array appear in reversed order. This does not mean that I can just need to display the elements in reverse order; I will actually move the last element in the array into the the first element of the array, and so on. I can't use a loop or create a new array.

The output should be

```
Original Array: 10 20 30 40 
Reversed Array: 40 30 20 10
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150131/java-recursively-reverse-an-array)?

Comment: No we are not allowed to use recursion

Comment: Without using iteration or recursion - this seems to be an impossible task. And also, it seems to be crowd sourcing a homework problem with little effort shown, so I am voting to close. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322514/reverse-an-array-without-using-iteration

Comment: This is what the teacher told me. I am lost as you. I don't really even know where to begin.

Comment: Can you swap them manually like `temp = arr[0]; arr[0]= arr[3]; arr[3]=tmp;` to swap border values, and then `temp = arr[1]; arr[1]=arr[2]; arr[2]=tmp;` to swap middle values.

Comment: When asking homework type questions, rather than simply dumping your assignment, please show your best good faith attempt to solve it and tell what problems you are having. This will give us a better understanding of what you're trying to do, what you might be doing wrong, what you need help with. Please have a look at How do I ask and answer [Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 8:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

// stuff

int[] reversed = IntStream.range(0,values.length).map(i -> values[values.length-i-1]).toArray();
```

Comment: You can't use other libraries. That defeats the purpose

Comment: I was attempting to answer the question I was given. Since you didn't specify restriction of external libraries in your question, I believe I did my best. In that case, it sounds like this is an assignment to practice recursion - and seeing as this question doesn't show your prior attempts I am voting for this question to be closed.

Comment: Our teacher said to redefine the arraylist.